# Change deprecated "public void onAttach(Activity a)" to what?

Tags: java, android

Code I downloaded from

`https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Fragments/Static`

contained the deprecated call mentioned in the Title.

I changed it as shown below and hoped for the best:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context a) { // was (Activity a)
    super.onAttach(a);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " onAttach()");
}
```

Android Studio 1.5.1 flagged no lines in any `.java` file after including

`import android.content.Context;`.

But I got this message:

`...fragmentsstatic W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 105: Landroid/app/Fragment;.onAttach (Landroid/content/Context;)V`

So what SHOULD I have done?

Note that execution proceded as expected with no exception.

Comment: You need to rethink your question. I can't understand what is it that you're trying to ask.

Comment: the method was deprecated with api 23, so running your code with a version lower than that will still use the old method

Comment: @TudorLuca--the question could be rephrased as this: "Since changing `Activity` to `Context` led to a message about `Context`, what change should I have made to avoid the message?". But I got a good Answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> contained the deprecated call mentioned in the Title.

Technically, it overrides a method deprecated in API Level 23. That project is set to compile with API Level 19.

> So what SHOULD I have done?

Option #1: Leave it alone. `onAttach(Activity)` works fine on API Level 11+ (since this is a native fragment; the backport works from API Level 4+). Android on API Level 23+ will try to find an `onAttach(Context)` and use it, and otherwise will fall back to `onAttach(Activity)`.

<strike>Option #2: Do what you did and ignore the warning. Since `Activity` extends `Context`, older devices looking for `onAttach(Activity)` should call `onAttach(Context)`. API Level 23+ devices looking for `onAttach(Context)` would be happy.</strike>

**UPDATE**: I just tried Option #2 with native fragments, and I was mistaken: older devices will ignore `onAttach(Context)`.

Option #3: Override both methods. <strike>There's a chance that</strike> API Level 23+ devices would call both; I haven't tried this. Older devices will still call `onAttach(Activity)`.

**UPDATE**: I just tried Option #3 with native fragments, and API Level 23+ devices will call through to both `onAttach()` flavors.

Comment: So "**deprecated**" doesn't mean "don't use this"...? When I see that a method or other item has a line drawn through it, it sure seems like "don't use this" is the message. I presume your remarks apply specifically to `onAttach` and not to deprecation in general, but I found this quote: "When you see 'deprecated' in the docs it usually means there is a better option that the Android team suggests you use instead." The argument continued with another guy saying "why bother deprecating 'it' if you don't intend to remove 'it' in some later release?"

Comment: @DSlomer64: The problem with deprecated stuff is that Google deprecates things at the drop of a hat. It's like they have a quota or something. As a result, determining whether "deprecated" means "run away screaming from it", "use it, with a plan to move away from it", or "use it anyway", is a bit of an art form. "When you see 'deprecated' in the docs it usually means there is a better option that the Android team suggests you use instead" -- that quote looks familiar. :-) And the key word there is "usually".

Comment: @DSlomer64: "why bother deprecating 'it' if you don't intend to remove 'it' in some later release?" -- Google *rarely* removes stuff outright, for backwards compatibility reasons. Apps written for Android 1.0 in 2008 still run on Android 6.0. They may have issues, but they run.

Comment: @CommonsWare--Thanks for the updates. And the Answer and other comments.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)

> public void onAttach (Activity activity)
>
> Added in API level 11 This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use
>   onAttach(Context) instead.